# Missing references to ProtoContract and ProtoMember in protobuf-net(3.2.26)

Tags: protobuf-net

Setup:
protubuf-net version 3.2.26
.Net Framework version 4.6.2

Problem:
Can't find references to ProtoContract and ProtoMember even if the ProtoBuf import is successful.

## .csproj file (referencing .targets file)

```
<Import Project="$(ComponentBuildPath)\ImportProtobufNet.targets" />
```

## ImportProtobufNet.targets

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <NewtonsoftJsonAlreadyImported>true</NewtonsoftJsonAlreadyImported>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="protobuf-net">
      <HintPath>$(Pkgprotobuf_net)\lib\net462\protobuf-net.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Where $Pkgprobuf_net is set by our build system and I've verified that this is correct.

I can't post the image of the expanded References in VS(coz I'm a new user). But, the references list protobuf-net.

My code:

```
using ProtoBuf;

    [ProtoContract]
    class MapElement
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string StartingIp { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public long Count { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(3)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Despite having the import done successful, I can't seem to find references to ProtoContract, ProtoMember in my code although the Serializer/Deserializer of ProtoBuf is available.

I tried inspecting the import using Object Browser but I can't find references to the missing attributes either. I found references to the Serializer/Deserializer methods though so I'm not sure if the attributes can be exposed using Object Browser.